# php Json remove double quotes for key and how to change name of the key

Tags: php, json

Sample Json

```
data:[{"varExchange":"ftx","varPrice":482.3},{"varExchange":"ftx","varPrice":481.8}]
```

1. I want to change the name of the key from "varExchange" to "name" and "varPrice" to "qty"
2. I need to remove the double quotes for key.

Output Like

```
 data:[{name:"test","qty":482.3},{name:"test","qty":481.8}]
```

Kindly help me to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: what is `data:[` ??

Answer (score 0):

First make proper input json array.

Then create new array as per your need for change the key

```js
var data = [{"varExchange":"ftx","varPrice":482.3},{"varExchange":"ftx","varPrice":481.8}];
var new_data = [];
for(var k in data){
  
  new_data.push({name : data[k].varExchange, qty : data[k].varPrice });
}

console.log(new_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its very simple..

1. Just convert the  JSON object to string by using json.stringify()
2. replace your substrings i.e.  "varExchange" with name and "varPrice" with qty.

and again you can cast it into object.